# JQuery Ajaxfrom and submitHandler how do they work together?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, ajaxform

am trying to put together Jquery Validate with submitHandler and Jquery plugin AjaxForm. The code below does not give any error but it does not call the php file or it seems to die somewhere. Unfortunately with firebug I got no errors. Without using the submitHandler it works ok. All necessary files are loaded.

```
$('#form-ev').validate({    
  rules: {
    .....
  }, //end rules
  messages: {
    ......
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $('.loading').fadeIn('slow');
    var insertOptions = { 
      url:       '/js/ajax/add.php',
      type:      'post',
      dataType:  'json', 
      clearForm: true,
      success: function(html) {
        if (html==1) {
          $('.loading').fadeOut();
          $('.success').delay(1500).fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
        } else {
          $('.error').show('slow').delay(2000).hide('slow');
        }
      }
    };

    $('#form-ev').ajaxForm(insertOptions);  
  }
});
```

Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried replacing this line :

```
$('#form-ev').ajaxForm(insertOptions);
```

with :

```
$('#form-ev').ajaxSubmit(insertOptions);
```

Comment: It does work replacing it but now the success: function(html) does not work as expected. I will look into this and see it can make it work. Thank you jbl. I will accept you answer.